# How to calculate the resulting explosion and implosion caused by shrinking and expanding a solid box

Tags: science-based, explosions

A character with Antman like powers I am thinking of have the magical ability to rapidly grow and shrink items. By rapidly, I mean able to do so in micro seconds.
I am trying to calculate the effects of resulting implosion and explosions a shrinking and expanding a box of say solid metal. For example a box whose sides are measured in nanometers suddenly expanding so that its sides are now a hundred meter in length and back again.

Comment: What sort of metal is that ductile? It would be atom-sized shrapnel immediately. And it's not even the most interesting question possible with the premise, there are FTL implications.

Answer (score 2):

The speed of light is three hundred meters per microsecond. Your description sounds like significant quantities of matter are being moved a hundred meters in a timescale on the order of a few microseconds, thereby being accelerated to on the order of a few percent of lightspeed.

To a distant observer, the result will look like a nuclear explosion. (To a nearby observer, it won't look like anything, for obvious reasons.)

There will be less fallout than from a hydrogen bomb, though more than none.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "whatever you want." Trying to give scientific explanations for the effects of super-powers is futile. They mostly break physics at a fundamental level, as your example does.

This is OK for story purposes but eliminates any possibility of scientific reasoning.

Comment: This is a poor answer. It can't just be "whatever you want". The mechanism itself is unscientific, sure, but there is nothing unscientific about finding the effects of expanding/collapsing objects in atmosphere.

Comment: Are they continuous objects? If the power is just moving the existing atoms around, there's very little effect, because the new box has no more surface area than the old one. If new atoms are appearing and disappearing, what happens to the air molecules infiltrating the enlarged box as it expands?

Comment: @BMF: Not without knowing a lot more about how the astonishing feat of expanding or contracting a box with relativistic speeds is to be performed, especially given the example of a cubic nanometer metal box expanding to a million cubic meter at 10% of the speed of light.

Comment: @AlexP I think OP's intent is clear. They aren't talking about a nanometer cube of material expanding into a larger cube of hard laboratory vacuum. Small solid objects expanding into larger *still solid* objects, displacing air. The "how" isn't important (there is no "how", it's all unphysical anyway), the question asks about the resulting effects.